# Registering GsonHttpMessageConverter instead of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, gson

I have created this class to add GSON to the spring-boot classpath. The problem, I cannot view any Html/text, or images content since there is not a valid converter.

I am relatively new to Spring-Boot.

I would like to to add Gson instead of Jackson to spring-boot and also be able to brow the web app using chrome.

Here is my class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class GsonSpringBootConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SyncController.class);

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        for(HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter : converters){
           log.info(httpMessageConverter.toString());
        }
        converters.add(createGsonHttpMessageConverter());

    }

    private GsonHttpMessageConverter createGsonHttpMessageConverter() {
        Gson gson = JsonUtils.getGsonBuilder();
        GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setGson(gson);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note the Javadoc of [`configureMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#configureMessageConverters-java.util.List-) states

> Configure the `HttpMessageConverter`s to use for reading or writing to
>   the body of the request or response. If no converters are added, a
>   default list of converters is registered.
>
> Note that adding converters to the list, **turns off default converter
>   registration**. To simply add a converter without impacting default
>   registration, consider using the method
>   `extendMessageConverters(java.util.List)` instead.

In other words, you've removed all the converters that handle other content types.

Note that Spring MVC only registers the Jackson `HttpMessageConverter` (`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`) if the corresponding Jackson libraries are in your classpath. You could remove them and, assuming you have Gson in your classpath, a `GsonHttpMessageConverter` will be registered for you.

From your code, it seems you want to create a custom `GsonHttpMessageConverter`. In that case, you can follow the Javadoc instructions and use [`extendMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#extendMessageConverters-java.util.List-).

> A hook for extending or modifying the list of converters after it has
>   been configured. This may be useful for example to allow default
>   converters to be registered and then insert a custom converter through
>   this method.

You'd first want to remove the existing instance, then add your own. For example,

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    // remove the Jackson version if Jackson is still in your classpath
    converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    // remove the existing instance (from defaults)
    converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof GsonHttpMessageConverter);
    // add your custom
    converters.add(createGsonHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Comment: @Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai, yes it did work for me.